# Making assumptions about parameter types and values?

Tags: python, validation, parameters

I have a bit of a stylistic question about parameter validation.

(Using Python)

Say I have a method with a parameter `a`, which needs to be an int, and maybe needs to be in a certain range - i.e. a list index or something. I could use assertions/other validation to ensure this, but what if I only call the function from one or two places, and the parameter is validated to the proper value/type there? Maybe its possible that the function could be called from other places in the future, but for now, it is 'basically' impossible to have an invalid parameter passed.

It feels unnecessary to add validation code to something that doesn't really need it, but it also seems sloppy to leave the function open to raising an uncaught error if its called from somewhere different.

Sorry if this is too abstract - I expect the answer may just be "it depends" but I was curious if there was a general consensus about this.

Comment: It really depends. For most cases, I'd keep the function simple and solve possible problems this with unittests. For parameters coming from "unpredictable source" (e.g. user), I use "full" validation possible (and also test it using unittests).

Comment: If a user input can raise an error, catch it and handle it.

Comment: Do you have a real life example? If not, the answer is going to be "it depends"

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it does not hurt to validate input parameters to a method every time it is called, even if it is unlikely that the parameters are wrong. The computational overhead is negligible in most cases (say checking type with `if type(x) is not int: raise TypeError` takes ~100 ns on my laptop, if the condition is verified). Besides, I'm not sure that doing conditional validation is worth it, with regards to code maintainability (it just makes things more complicated).

Of course, this is also problem specific. For instance, if you have a computationally critical function that is called repeatedly (say more then million times) within a loop, it is probably worth skipping the  validation step and check the parameters beforehand.